# banana with solr in CDH 5.13

Tags: solr4, banana

I am trying to access banana in CDH 5.13 which has solr 4.10.3.

I copied the banana release folder from github into the directory

```
/usr/lib/solr/webapps/banana
```

and restarted zookeeper and solr servers. But I am not able to access banana dashboard?

I am getting below error when I access the url 
http://quickstart.cloudera:8983/solr/banana/src/index.html

```
http 404: /solr/banana/src/index.html 

requested resource is not available
```

please share your inputs on this issue.

Thanks,
Phani.

Comment: Looks like the URL has extra /solr, should be http://quickstart.cloudera:8983/banana/src/index.html

Comment: Thanks Aadel, yes there is an extra solr in the url....actually I should place the files in  /usr/lib/solr/webapps/solr/banana then the url I mentioned will work.                                                                                                                        but I am not able to view the data from any solr collection in banana . I have created the banana-int using the solrctl in solrcloud.                         Not sure what is still missing...please let me know if I have to check any other configuration

Comment: make sure that timepicker field is set to a datetime field, or it has no fields, and check that filters ranges return data. As long as you are able to select collection and you don't see any error messages, the connection with Solr is established. Do you have some panels working and others not?

Comment: None of them are fetching data. I could not find much documentation on it. Can u please point me to any sources other than GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was using time series dashboard without any datetime field in solr. Making the field a datetime or when using the non-time series dashboard will allow the data to be viewed.